# How to wrap axis label in Altair

Tags: python, altair

```
bars = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
            x=alt.X('Pcnt:Q', axis=None),
            y=alt.Y('Name', 
                    axis=alt.Axis(domain=False, 
                                  ticks=False, 
                                  title=None, 
                                  labelPadding=15, 
                                  labelFontSize=16, 
                                  labelColor='#404040',
                                  labelBaseline='middle',
#                                   labelAngle= -45,
#                                   labelExpr=axis_labels
                                 ), 
                    sort=name_sort
                   )
    )

text = bars.mark_text(align='left', baseline='middle', dx=3, size=14).\
encode(text=alt.Text('Pcnt:Q',format='.0%'))

Votes = (bars+text).properties(width=500,height=100
                    ).properties(title={
                                      "text": ["Who Shot First?"], 
                                      "subtitle": ["According to 834 respondents"],
                                      "fontSize": 26,  "color": '#353535',
                                      "subtitleFontSize": 20,  "subtitleColor": '#353535',    
                                      "anchor": 'start'}
                    ).configure_mark(color='#008fd5'
                    ).configure_view(strokeWidth=0
                    ).configure_scale(bandPaddingInner=0.2
                    )
Votes
```

Currently (see below output), the third label in y-axis (i.e. "I don't understand this question") got truncated. I want to wrap it to make the whole label visible. Anyone can help? Thank you very much!

[image]

Desired chart is like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is the best way to do it since we don't know the entire text that is being challenged, but there is a way to split the string with whitespace. `.transform_calculate(y="split(datum.y, ' ')")` [Line break or word wrap for labels in axis](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2376)

Comment: Hi, instead of splitting the string with whitespace, is there another way? After all, there are multiple whitespaces in this label. Thank you!

Comment: The split used here is python, so other string functions may be able to handle it. As a reluctant technique, how about replacing the whitespace in the place where you want to split with an underscore? `.transform_calculate(y="split(datum.y, '_')")`

Comment: Thank you. Ya, that would be an option, but I wish Altair can wrap the label without changing the string in the source data...for example, instead of splitting by a char, would it be possible to split by # of characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `labelLimit` to control when the label is truncated:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': ['Really long label here that will be truncated', 'Short label'],
    'value': [4, 5]
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='value',
    y='label'
)
```

[image]

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='value',
    y=alt.Y('label', axis=alt.Axis(labelLimit=200))
)
```

[image]

---

You can also wrap on multiple lines by creating a list, as suggested in the comments:

```
from textwrap import wrap


# Wrap on whitespace with a max line length of 30 chars
df['label'] = df['label'].apply(wrap, args=[30])

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='value',
    y=alt.Y('label', axis=alt.Axis(labelFontSize=9)),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The two options are great! I wish Altair can provide an easy way to wrap long labels, e.g. based on # of characters or by pixels, so that we don't need to add extra space for long labels, nor do we need to change the string in the source data. If we change the string in source data and also want to sort the bars based on labels, it would take an extra manual step.